# Couldn't capture radiobutton group change event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a cordova android application where i use jquery for the development. I'm using a radio button group where radio buttons are created dynamically using the below code,

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++){

            var j = i+1;

            $('#childInfoRadioGroup').prepend('<input type="radio" class="radioInput" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-"'+j+' value="on">'+
             '<label for="radio-choice-v-"'+j+'>'+jsonArr[i].name+'</label>').trigger('create');    

            $('#childInfoRadioGroup input').eq(i).attr("id",jsonArr[i].id);

}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="childInfoRadioGroup">

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

i used the below code for capturing the change event,

```
$("input[name='radio-choice-v-2']").on("change", function () {
    alert("changed!");
});
```

But i'm not able to capture above event. Any one have any idea?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are generating HTML dynamically ,try **event delegation** as shown below :-

```
$(document.body).on("change","input[name='radio-choice-v-2']", function () {
    alert("changed!");
});
```

OR

```
$("#childInfoRadioGroup").on("change","input[name='radio-choice-v-2']", function () {
    alert("changed!");
});
```

[Reference](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: can we do like this > $("input[name='radio-choice-v-2']").change(function () ? just asking :)

Comment: @akz, No. You can't do like that because radio button group created dynamically that is why we have to use event delegation method.

Comment: @akz..no..the problem is that you are generating html dynamically by jquery itself so you have to use event delegation as shown in this answer.

Comment: @RGS and Kartikeya thanks i was bit confuse with that and u plz don't confuse with akz and akh lol they both r not same . :) thanks  a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("change","input[name='radio-choice-v-2']", function () {
    alert("changed!");
});
```